# How to get count from another table (zero when no data) using single query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have two tables - 'Offered' and 'joined'. I need count of 'offered_id' from joined table and zero when not found. My tables and output required is below. How can I achieve this using single query in mysql ?

```
TABLE : OFFERED
===============
offered_id    data
-----------   ----
    1         aaaa
    2         bbbb
    3         cccc
    4         dddd
    5         eeee
    6         ffff

TABLE : JOINED
===============
joined_id      offered_id
-----------    ----------
    1               5
    2               2
    3               2
    4               1
    5               3
    6               2
    7               5

OUTPUT REQUIRED
===============
offered_id      data     count(offered_id) from joined table.(0 for no entry)
-----------    -----     ------------------------------------------------
    1           aaaa          1
    2           bbbb          3
    3           cccc          1
    4           dddd          0
    5           eeee          1
    6           ffff          0
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt ?

Comment: this is the situation where joins comes in action ..;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sub query you can achieve that...

```
SELECT OFFERED.offered_id, OFFERED.data, (SELECT COUNT(JOINED.joined_id) FROM JOINED WHERE JOINED.offered_id = OFFERED.offered_id) AS count_joined FROM OFFERED
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `count` :

```
SELECT OFFERED.OFFERED_id,OFFERED.data,(select count(JOINED.joined_id) FROM JOINED INNER JOIN OFFERED
ON JOINED.offered_id = OFFERED.offered_id) as count_joined FROM OFFERED
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try it helps me to achieve the same thing for my project and it will surely help you.

```
SELECT offered_id FROM OFFERED WHERE offered_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT offered_id FROM JOINED)
```